# Are Web Workers good for parallel stream calls from server(lots of data)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, streaming, web-worker

Are Web Workers good for parallel stream calls from server(lots of data)?
(I use GRPC for interacting with backend)

Comment: Streams are generally `async`, so that part would not benefit.  But it's what you do with the data when you get it, if that's CPU intensive then a webWorker may be of benefit.

Comment: There is no heavy calculation. Just collecting data and pass them through components

Answer (score 2):

Well, web workers are great but they are intented to be used for computational expensive tasks which are CPU bound, because tasks like those are the ones that can block your UI thread and ruin UX by freezing application completely until CPU bound tasks are not being resolved.

On the other side, I/O operations handled by javascript async execution are concurrent and by the nature of Event Loop they will not block UI thread because once call is stared it will be immediately offloaded from UI thread, until resolved, and like that async call will never be blocking for application UI - meaning there is really no any significant benefit if you decide to move async execution to dedicated worker thread via web workers in javascript.